# Excel interpolate with hlookup

Tags: excel, interpolation

I have a table with x,y values. I want to interpolate for a given x1 value between the y values using the hllokup function also. I have found fomrulas for vlookup and xlookup but not for hlookup. I cannot use xlookup becaus eogf the verison of excel I use.

Example:

```
x-values  0.2  0.5  0.8  1.0  1.25  1.5  1.75  2.0  2.5  3.0  4.0
y-values  0.1  0.11 0.12 0.15 0.18  0.2  0.23  0.24 0.28 0.31 0.32
```

I need the y-value for x=1.1

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to interpolate: spline, polynomial, linear and so on.
I assume that you want linear interpolation between 2 x values.
In this case first of all, you need to find closest larger and closest lower x values:

Lower x:

```
=MAX(IF(B1:L1<B5,B1:L1))
```

Larger x:

```
=MIN(IF(B1:L1>B5,B1:L1))
```

Now need to find corresponding y's with `HLOOKUP`.

Lower x's y:

```
=HLOOKUP(A9,B1:L2,2,FALSE)
```

Larger x's y:

```
=HLOOKUP(B9,B1:L2,2,FALSE)
```

Now that you have all needed values you can write linear interpolation formula or you can use excel formula `FORECAST`. With 2 x's and 2 y's it will work as linear interpolation.

```
=FORECAST(B5,A11:B11,A9:B9)
```

Formula without using helper cells:

```
=FORECAST(B5,CHOOSE({1,2},HLOOKUP(MAX(IF(B1:L1<B5,B1:L1)),B1:L2,2,FALSE),HLOOKUP(MIN(IF(B1:L1>B5,B1:L1)),B1:L2,2,FALSE)),CHOOSE({1,2},MAX(IF(B1:L1<B5,B1:L1)),MIN(IF(B1:L1>B5,B1:L1))))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer. Although I believe this works, as you described, I cannot get the same functions work for me. I only changed the commas , with questionairs ; as I work with another version of excel. However I get 4.00 instead of 1.0 and 0.00 instead of 1.25. As the 0.00 values is not availavle in the table the hlookup turns an error. I tried these formulas at this specific example, although my real table has more rows.

Comment: , and ; are due to regional settings. Though those are very simple formulas and should work with 2010+ excel, what version do you use? Also it is possible to get values you mentioned if input in B5 is text value instead of number. If you use ; as separator maybe your decimal should be , and not .? Try 1,1 instead of 1.1 and attach a screen with recreated example in my answer

Comment: Yes these are regional settings and I have changed also the decimal distinction. The cella are also numbers. I cannot find out why it is not working with me. Whereas if I tansponse the tabel and work with vlookup and match functions it is much more easier.

Comment: Hard to debug not seeing your worksheet

Comment: Hello. Pleas take a look at the following snapshots. See that if I move the cells with the fomrula the values change,which I also cannot understand.   https://imgur.com/a/xrLTZnl

Comment: Very strange behavior. Values 0 and 4 are on left side of cell which means that it is text not a number (if formatting is not altered). Also I see that you get #TIMH error. It is not standard english error. What language do you use? Is it possible that formulas if, max, min has other names in that language?

Comment: Also you did not mention what Excel version you use. Try CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when entering those formulas

Comment: I use Excel 2016. It does not work with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. However thank you very much. I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Consider raising a new question here in SO if you think that formulas doesn't work as they should.